# Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin Can't Run Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to kickoff a build using Jenkins Build Pipeline plugin as follows:

```
build 'App - App Rest API'
```

That job has a sbt build step that is set up like this:

[image: sbt build setup]

The build fails to run with the following error:

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ App - App Rest API about clean publish
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Pipeline - App API/workspace@tmp/durable-a4b7f495/script.sh: line 2: App: command not found
```

What I don't understand is why it's trying to run the "App - App Rest API" as a command. Anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jenkins doesn't escape spaces, so use following command to workaround that:

```
build 'App\\ -\\ App\\ Rest\\ API'
```

Comment: Or better to not use spaces in the name

Comment: That also didn't work. I changed it to `build 'App\\ -\\ App\\ Rest\\ API` and got the following error: `[workspace] Running shell script
+ 'App - App Rest API' about clean publish
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Pipeline - App API/workspace@tmp/durable-2d41fbdc/script.sh: line 2: App - App Rest API: command not found`

Comment: Am I wrong or does it look like it's trying to run `'App - App Rest API' about clean publish` as a shell script?

Comment: Also, for sanity's sake, I renamed the job so that it has no spaces. I get the same error: `[workspace] Running shell script
+ AppRestAPI about clean publish
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Pipeline - App API/workspace@tmp/durable-59452f30/script.sh: line 2: AppRestAPI: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so this was stupidity on my part (sometimes it's self deprecation, other times it's not... this falls into the latter category :-P ). I had the following function in my pipeline code that was obscuring the default build function:

```
def build(sbtCmd) {
    echo "Building App API"
    sh "${sbtCmd} about clean publish"
}
```

Removing that fixed my issue. Thanks for the help!

Oh, and for the record, spaces don't need to be escaped using the built in `build` command.